# IntelliJ 2021.1.1 -> 2021.1.2- Some conflicts were found in the installation area

Tags: intellij-idea

Small question regarding an IntelliJ update that is failing please.

Currently using version 2021.1.1, I received a notification asking me to update to 2021.1.2, which I would like to.

Downloaded, and during the installation, I am seeing:

```
Some conflicts were found in the installation area 

Some of the conflicts below do not have a solution, so the patch cannot be applied.
Please download this version from the developer Web site and install it from scratch.
Press 'Cancel' to exit.
```

Then, I can see my path to cacert with `action = update, problem = modified solution = none`

May I ask what is the issue please? Is there a way to resolve it without having to reinstall from scratch?

Thank you

Comment: What is the file path in conflict?

Comment: jbr/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> May I ask what is the issue please?

The reason is that during the patch update procedure it will not be possible to verify the integrity of the installation and that it will be properly patched because it has been modified (possibly manually).

> Is there a way to resolve it without having to reinstall from scratch?

No, unfortunately, the only right solution is to download the full distribution.